# How to fork a stream using highland.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, stream, highland.js

I have a `sourceStream` consisting of `BaseData` objects.

I want to fork this stream into `n`-amount of different streams, which then filter and transform each `BaseData` object to their liking.

In the end, I want to have `n` streams only containing a specific type and the forked streams can vary in their length, as data might be dropped or added in the future.

I thought I could set it up this via `fork`:

```
import * as _ from 'highland';

interface BaseData {
    id: string;
    data: string;
}

const sourceStream = _([
    {id: 'foo', data: 'poit'},
    {id: 'foo', data: 'fnord'},
    {id: 'bar', data: 'narf'}]);

const partners = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
];

partners.forEach((partner: string) => {
    const partnerStream = sourceStream.fork();

    partnerStream.filter((baseData: BaseData) => {
        return baseData.id === partner;
    });

    partnerStream.each(console.log);
});
```

I expected to now have two streams, and the `foo`-stream to contain two elements:

```
{ id: 'foo', data: 'poit' }
{ id: 'foo', data: 'fnord' }
```

and the `bar`-stream to contain one element:

```
{ id: 'bar', data: 'narf' }
```

Yet I get an error instead:

```
/usr/src/marketing-tasks/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:1338
        throw new Error(
        ^

Error: Stream already being consumed, you must either fork() or observe()
    at Stream._addConsumer (/usr/src/marketing-tasks/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:1338:15)
    at Stream.consume (/usr/src/marketing-tasks/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:1500:10)
    at Stream.each (/usr/src/marketing-tasks/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:1774:18)
    at partners.forEach (/usr/src/marketing-tasks/dist/bin/example.js:17:19)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/marketing-tasks/dist/bin/example.js:12:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

How to fork a stream into multiple streams?

---

I also tried chaining the calls, yet then I only get back one stream's result:

```
partners.forEach((partner: string) => {
    console.log(partner);
    const partnerStream = sourceStream
        .fork()
        .filter((item: BaseData) => {
            return item.id === partner;
        });

    partnerStream.each((item: BaseData) => {
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

Printing only:

```
foo
{ id: 'foo', data: 'poit' }
{ id: 'foo', data: 'fnord' }
bar
```

Instead of the expected:

```
foo
{ id: 'foo', data: 'poit' }
{ id: 'foo', data: 'fnord' }
bar
{id: 'bar', data: 'narf'}
```

---

It may also be the case that I misunderstood was `fork` was all about. As per [its doc entry](http://highlandjs.org/#fork):

> Stream.fork() Forks a stream, allowing you to add additional consumers
>   with shared back-pressure. A stream forked to multiple consumers will
>   only pull values from its source as fast as the slowest consumer can
>   handle them.
>
> NOTE: Do not depend on a consistent execution order between the forks.
>   This transform only guarantees that all forks will process a value foo
>   before any will process a second value bar. It does not guarantee the
>   order in which the forks process foo.
>
> TIP: Be careful about modifying stream values within the forks (or
>   using a library that does so). **Since the same value will be passed to
>   every fork, changes made in one fork will be visible in any fork that
>   executes after it.** Add to that the inconsistent execution order, and
>   you can end up with subtle data corruption bugs. If you need to modify
>   any values, you should make a copy and modify the copy instead.
>
> Deprecation warning: It is currently possible to fork a stream after
>   consuming it (e.g., via a transform). This will no longer be possible
>   in the next major release. If you are going to fork a stream, always
>   call fork on it.

So instead of "How to fork a stream?" my actual question might be: How to duplicate a highland stream on the fly into different streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must bear in mind not to consume a forked stream before all forks are created. As if one consumes a forked stream, it and its "parent" will be consumed, making any subsequent fork being forked from an empty stream.

```
const partnerStreams: Array<Stream<BaseData>> = [];

partners.forEach((partner: string) => {
    const partnerStream = sourceStream
        .fork()
        .filter((item: BaseData) => {
            return item.id === partner;
         }
    );

    partnerStreams.push(partnerStream);
});

partnerStreams.forEach((stream, index) => {
    console.log(index, stream);
    stream.toArray((foo) => {
        console.log(index, foo);
    });
});
```

It prints:

```
0 [ { id: 'foo', data: 'poit' }, { id: 'foo', data: 'fnord' } ]
1 [ { id: 'bar', data: 'narf' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`partnerStream.filter()` returns a *new* stream. You're then consuming `partnerStream` again using `partnerStream.each()`, without calling `fork()` or `observe()`. So either chain the `partnerStream.filter().each()` calls or assign the return value of `partnerStream.filter()` to a variable and call `.each()` on that.

Comment: I have updated my question as now I don't see an error, yet I only see the return values of one stream, not both of them.